# Tensorflow: executing an ops with a specific core of a CPU

Tags: graph, cpu, device, tensorflow

It is currently possible to specify which CPU or GPU to use with the tf.device(...) function for specific ops, but is there anyway where you can specify a *core* of a CPU?

Answer (score 24):

There's no API for pinning ops to a particular core at present, though this would make a good [feature request](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues). You could approximate this functionality by creating multiple CPU devices, each with a single-threaded threadpool, but this isn't guaranteed to maintain the locality of a core-pinning solution:

```
with tf.device("/cpu:4"):
  # ...

with tf.device("/cpu:7"):
  # ...

with tf.device("/cpu:0"):
  # ...

config = tf.ConfigProto(device_count={"CPU": 8},
                        inter_op_parallelism_threads=1,
                        intra_op_parallelism_threads=1)
sess = tf.Session(config=config)
```

Comment: Wow, just with a simple test the speed gain was 3 folds. Thank you so much!

EDIT: After investigation, the 3 fold gain in speed is only caused by setting the config as described in your answer. It makes sens giving that I am using RNN. I will look into this!

Comment: BTW, I think you need to set inter_op_parallelism_threads to higher numer in the example above, otherwise it will run everything sequentially, here's a test https://gist.github.com/yaroslavvb/b73ff35424dd7ab762234620cf583aac

Comment: I want only one thread. However, config = tf.ConfigProto(device_count={"CPU": 1},
                        inter_op_parallelism_threads=1,
                        intra_op_parallelism_threads=1) generates 8 threads (One thread per core and I have 8 cores). How can I reduce the number of threads to 1?