# Does TensorFlow view all CPUs of one machine as ONE device?

Tags: python, tensorflow

From the experiments I run, it seems like TensorFlow uses automatically all CPUs on one machine. Furthermore, it seems like TensorFlow refers to all CPUs as /cpu:0.

Am I right, that only the different GPUs of one machine get indexed and viewed as separate devices, but all the CPUs on one machine get viewed as a single device?

Is there any way that a machine can have multiple CPUs viewing it from TensorFlows perspective?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

By default all CPUs available to the process are aggregated under `cpu:0` device.

There's answer by mrry [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37864489/419116) showing how to create logical devices like `/cpu:1`, `/cpu:2`

There doesn't seem to be working functionality to pin logical devices to specific physical cores or be able to use NUMA nodes in tensorflow.

A possible work-around is to use distributed TensorFlow with multiple processes on one machine and use `taskset` on Linux to pin specific processes to specific cores

Comment: can you give me a hint (source code location) to where Tensorflow, uses multi cores of "one" CPU to run one partition of a graph? Because as far as I understood, TF divides the graph into partitions and each partition will be run on one device by its corresponding executor. But my question is  how cpu with multi cores executes a partition?

Comment: I want TensorFlow not to see/know other cores except one. How can I do that?