# How To Let Tensorflow Use All CPU

Tags: python, linux, tensorflow

My Linux has 2 CPUs (16 cores per CPU). Each core has 2 threads.

CPU usage rate only 50% less if i use `tf.Session(tf.ConfigProto())`

CPU usage rate only 40% less if i use `tf.Session(tf.ConfigProto(device_count={"CPU": 64}))`

Cpu usage rate is 30-70% if i use `tf.ConfigProto(device_count={"CPU": 32},
                                inter_op_parallelism_threads=1,
                                intra_op_parallelism_threads=64,
                                )`

And in this configuration all cores are working, but the usage rate is only 30-80%

I have tested in Windows Server (1 cpu / 4 cores). Cpu usage rate is more than 90%.

what should I code can let Tensorflow use all cpu?

Comment: Related, [Does TensorFlow job use multiple cores by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42845261/608639) and [Does TensorFlow view all CPUs of one machine as ONE device?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38836269/608639)

Comment: Make sure your I/O and GPU aren't blocking.