# Build generator for model predict

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I'm trying to use generator as the input for model predict function,

```
prediction = model.predict(generator)
```

I created my generator in this way

```
generator = tf.keras.preprocessing.sequence.TimeseriesGenerator(x_feature,y_target, length=n_input,batch_size = 1024)
```

My question are:

1.Is this a correct way of creating generator for predict function ?

2.If it is, why it takes target value as input, if it's not, what kind of generator is expected here?

I'm using generator since my dataset does not fit my memory, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58202668/how-to-write-a-generator-for-keras-model-for-predict-generator), but this question does not show how to create a generator.

Thank you!

Comment: your question is pretty vague. Try it with a simple example, see what error you get, and then post.

Comment: @MaMaG Hi, sorry for the confusion, I edited my questipon, my question is just asking how to create a generator for predict function.