# How do the `intra_op_parallelism_threads` and `inter_op_parallelism_threads` options work in TensorFlow?

Tags: multithreading, configuration, tensorflow, gpu

My understanding is that TensorFlow creates two thread pools on each device: one for intra op parallelism and one for inter op parallelism.

Suppose there are 3 independent ops A, B, C placed on `/gpu:0` and `intra_op_parallelism_threads=5`. Suppose A and B have a single-threaded GPU kernel implementation, and C has a multi-threaded kernel implementation, does that mean that they can all run in parallel on the same device, A and B using just 1 GPU thread while C uses up to 3 GPU threads?

Now suppose `inter_op_parallelism_threads=2`, does that mean that only 2 out of 3 ops can be evaluated simultaneously on `/gpu:0`, so in the example above, it may be A+B, B+C or A+C depending on who gets there first?

Note: I'm trying to make sense of @mrry's answer to this question: [Tensorflow: executing an ops with a specific core of a CPU](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37864081/tensorflow-executing-an-ops-with-a-specific-core-of-a-cpu/37864489#37864489)

Comment: intra_op_parallelism_threads affects the number of threads in Eigen threadpool, so it has no effect on GPU operations. GPU ops tend to grab the whole GPU