# How Tensorflow uses CPU cores by default?

Tags: c++, tensorflow, parallel-processing

Assume we don't have any `GPUs`. We have a single machine which has one `CPU` with `N` cores. I want to train a neural network on the CPU and want to utilize the CPU as much as possible.

I know that I can set `inter_op_parallelism_threads` and `intra_op_parallelism_threads`variables to control over parallelism in Tensorflow. But I want to know how Tensorflow handles parallelism across CPU cores by default?

My initial guess is **by default**, Tensorflow sees all the CPU cores as one device and use them to run one **single** operation concurrently across all the cores using `Eigen` library and we don't have any inter_op parallelism (which means running mutli ops in parallel).

I know about this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37864081/tensorflow-executing-an-ops-with-a-specific-core-of-a-cpu/37864489#37864489). But this is not what I'm looking for. I want to know how tensorflow itself handles parallelism across CPU cores.

Comment: if you want to optimize for CPU, you should probably use MKL version (the default conda version on Linnux I believe), it will use as many cores at it can by default

Comment: Thanks @YaroslavBulatov, does that mean the tensorflow does not use inter_op_parallelism_threads by default for a multi core cpu?

Answer (score 0):

I have some problems with similar question. Posted my solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68954373/why-tensorflow-uses-100-of-all-cpu-cores).
I use an intel processor, which have some CPU optimization parameters (openMP) for threading with keras processes,

```
import os
os.environ["OMP_NUM_THREADS"] = “16”
```