# why tensorflow uses 100% of all CPU cores?

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, cpu

I've made a fresh install of Jupyter Notebook kernel and python packages, including tensorflow 2.4.1 (using miniconda env).

When I train and test a model, my CPU usage saturate. In my old install, that's not happen (low CPU usage), and the time to accomplish the tasks was barely the same.

Is there a config of jupyter and/or tensorflow?
I've test on Jupyter Notebook and VSCode, the same problem occurs.
Ubuntu 20.04
16GB RAM
Intel® Core™ i5-8300H CPU @ 2.30GHz × 8

[CPU usage when training a simple network model - htop view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GfTzt.png)

**Edit**:  Condition solved.

I've done a deep research on intel website, and found this [link](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/guide-to-tensorflow-runtime-optimizations-for-cpu.html), about threading config. for Tensorflow and openMP. I run some quick tests varying the tensorflow 2.x section paramenters below, giving back no improvement.

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.config.threading.set_inter_op_parallelism_threads() 
tf.config.threading.set_intra_op_parallelism_threads()
tf.config.set_soft_device_placement(enabled)
```

then I test the openMP settings, changing `OMP_NUM_THREADS` from 0 to 8, as reported on the graph below:

[training time vs OMP_NUM_THREADS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qp95K.png)

```
import os
os.environ["OMP_NUM_THREADS"] = “16”
```

CPU usage reduced, with lower training time.

[CPU usage for OMP_NUM_THREADS equal to 0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zerd6.png)

OBS.: I am not an expert in ML benchmarks. Just fixed a network training parameters and topology for `keras.Sequential()` model. Don't know the reason why my CPU was threading at maximum `OMP_NUM_THREADS=16` by default.

Comment: Souds like an excellent efficient use of your CPU cores.

Comment: Do you want it to be less. While I don't know TensorFlow, I seem to recall there are straightforward options to set the number of cores/threads to be used.

Comment: "and the time to accomplish the tasks was barely the same.": are the results the same? Perhaps one has better results than the other.

Comment: The problem is that my laptop lags, because i need to work on other tasks when training is being performed. The results are the same, there is no reduction in training time also.

Comment: I think i solved the condition. You're right, the CPU cores were threading very nice, but this is not bringing processing time improvement for my problem (keras simple sequential model). Changed the `os.environ["OMP_NUM_THREADS"] = 1` and CPU uses reduces drastically, reducing the training time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In our multiuser environment we need to keep some of the cpu's free for higher prioritized jobs (we don't have the rights to 'nice' processes). So reducing tensorflows (Version 2.8.2) cpu-greed is quite essential. The abovementioned solution works in our purely cpu environment (linux, 40 cores) with a restriction of the inter/intra-threads to 1.

```
import os
os.environ["OMP_NUM_THREADS"] = “8”

import tensorflow as tf
tf.config.threading.set_inter_op_parallelism_threads(1) 
tf.config.threading.set_intra_op_parallelism_threads(1)
```

This restricts the cpu-usage to 800%.